# How to write a JavaScript promise decorator

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a preexisting JavaScript function that returns a promise. I call it like so

```
function on_success(result){
  //process result
}
foo(params).then(on_success)
```

I would like to write wrapper function, bar, that will call foo and and measure execution time. I want to call bar in the exact same manner:

```
bar(params).then(on_success)
```

ho do I do that?

This is what I ended up writing. It is a simplified version of @Sidney answer

```
function bar(params){
    var start_time=new Date().getTime()
    function print_time(x){
        var end_time=new Date().getTime()
        console.log(end_time-start_time)
        return x
    }
    return foo(params).then(print_time)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're looking for something like this:

```js
const myAsyncFunction = url =>
  fetch(url).then(res => res.text())
  
const timePromise = (promiseFn, ...args) => {
  const start = Date.now()
  return promiseFn(...args)
    .then(result => {
      console.log(`Promise finished in ${(Date.now() - start) / 1000} seconds`)
      return result
    }, error => {
      console.log(`Promise errored in ${(Date.now() - start) / 1000} seconds`)
      return Promise.reject(error)
    })
}

timePromise(myAsyncFunction, 'https://example.com')
```

Comment: this the closest  solution, but see a simplification on the question body

Answer (score 0):

You can handle a fulfilled promise, in your case to stop the measurement, and then pass on the return value of `then`, which will be a promise in itself:

```
function measure (measuredFunction) {
    startMeasurement()

    return measuredFunction()
        .then(stopMeasurement)
}

measure(() => foo(params)).then(on_success)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic, least fancy way you could do it...

```js
var timer = new Date().getTime();

function foo(){
  return new Promise(done=>{
    setTimeout(done, 1000);
  })
}

function on_success(result){
  //process result
  alert("it took "+(new Date().getTime() - timer)+"ms to do that...")
}

let params = {}

foo(params).then(on_success)
```